# SQL - displaying zero results

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I am looking to display a 'O' or 'No results found' when no records are found based off my query but can't get it right.  I think the problem comes from that I am trying to display information about the records I am counting along with how many there are that fit the criteria.  Perhaps its not the count that I need to change with ISNULL but something to modify the result if no rows are outputted.

Thanks for any help in advance.

```
select t3.countyname, t2.titleunitname, t1.transdesc, count (isnull(t3.orderkey,0)) as c1
        from tblorder as t3
        left join qryOrderRecord1 as t1 on t3.OrderKey = t1.OrderKey
        left join qrytitleunits as t2 on t3.titleunitnum = t2.titleunitnum
        WHERE t1.transdesc = 'LETTERS'
        AND (t3.OrderDateTime between '7/7/2010' AND '7/7/2010')
        AND t3.countyname = 'Frankfurt'
        AND t2.titleunitname = 'Maxwell'
        group by t3.countyname,t1.transdesc, t2.titleunitname
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to count `t1.orderkey` t3 is on the left side of the outer join so it is the `t1.orderkey` values that will be `NULL`.

Also I moved the Filters on t1 and t2 into the `JOIN` conditions not the `WHERE` clause

If that doesn't do the trick providing some sample data in your question will help.

```
SELECT t3.countyname,
    t2.titleunitname,
    t1.transdesc    ,
    COUNT(t1.orderkey) AS c1 /*As dotjoe's answer suggests*/
FROM tblorder                     AS t3
    LEFT JOIN qryOrderRecord1     AS t1
    ON  t3.OrderKey  = t1.OrderKey
    AND t1.transdesc = 'LETTERS'
    LEFT JOIN qrytitleunits AS t2
    ON  t3.titleunitnum  = t2.titleunitnum
    AND t2.titleunitname = 'Maxwell'
WHERE t3.OrderDateTime BETWEEN '7/7/2010' AND '7/7/2010' /*Seems odd! Should these be 
                                                           different dates?*/
AND t3.countyname = 'Frankfurt'
GROUP BY t3.countyname,
    t1.transdesc      ,
    t2.titleunitname
```

Comment: +1 yes OP effectively turned those outer joins into inner joins by placing restrictions in the where clause. good point.

Comment: oops I think I meant to place my comment after this answer not the other one.  still getting a hang of posting here obviously >_<

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1250819/show-message-when-no-rows-selected-mysql-php

That's what I was trying to do but with sql & php.  Looks like I need to do it on the php end.  Thanks for the help anyway.

Comment: @bnw - Oh I see. Yes best to do that on the PHP end.

Answer (score 2):

That `count(isnull(column, 0))` is the same as `count(1)` or `count(*)`. See this question for the why...

[Count(*) vs Count(1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1221559/count-vs-count1)

Maybe you want `count(t1.orderkey)`? This would not count any null t1.orderkey's.

Comment: Thanks for the help in cleaning up the sql.  I realized what I am wanting is much simpler then my question/code implied.

use adventureworks

SELECT AddressID<br/>

FROM Person.Address

where PostalCode = '63108'


Is there a way to display a message like "no results in search" if no results/rows are found?

Comment: Yes, generally that would be handled by the consumer of the query. I suppose you could check `if @@rowcount = 0 begin select 'No results'; end` right after the select. But, that would give you 2 result sets...first one with no rows. Or select into a table variable, check for rows and deterine which result set to return. Much simpler to let code that calls the query handle this.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot.

```
select t3.countyname, t2.titleunitname, t1.transdesc, count (isnull(t3.orderkey,0)) as c1 
into #Tmp
from tblorder as t3 
    left join qryOrderRecord1 as t1 on t3.OrderKey = t1.OrderKey 
    left join qrytitleunits as t2 on t3.titleunitnum = t2.titleunitnum 
where t1.transdesc = 'LETTERS' 
  AND (t3.OrderDateTime between '7/7/2010' AND '7/7/2010') 
  AND t3.countyname = 'Frankfurt' 
  AND t2.titleunitname = 'Maxwell' 
group by t3.countyname,t1.transdesc, t2.titleunitname 

if @@ROWCOUNT > 0
    select *
    from #Tmp
else
    select 'No Results Found.'
```